# Python requests library returns html rather than json

Tags: python, json, twitter, python-requests

I am trying to pull the tweets with some keywords (donaldtrump in the following example). My code used to work about a month ago. Now I started to get `Error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error.

```
import requests, json
url='https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=%20since%3A2020-01-11%20until%3A2020-06-12%20donaldtrump&src=typd&max_position=&raw=true'
responseheaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0)'' Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0'}
REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 10
response = requests.get(url, headers=responseheaders, timeout=REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
dataJson=response.json()
```

I think somehow the requests.get returns html rather than json. Because following code returns `text/html;charset=utf-8`.

```
print(response.headers.get('Content-Type'))
```

I tried converting the html to json but it does not work. I don't know what has changed in the last month and broke this script. I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What does the HTML result say? You are not checking for errors here. Check `status_code` and the HTML.

Comment: I've shared only a part of the code. I am already checking the status code and it is 200.

Comment: Not sure about what to check in the html.

Comment: The title should have said "python requests library returns html rather than json"

Comment: I don't understand why you think it would return a JSON. You open this URL and can see it just does not return a JSON.

Comment: This doesn't look like twitter API. A normal URL which shows a web-page normally, would, give HTML only when requested using `requests`.

Comment: you need to use the Twitter Search API to get Tweets as JSON

Comment: It used to return a Json file about a month ago hence the expectation.

Comment: About the Twitter Search API, as far as I know it does not allow you to search before a certain date that's why I am trying to scrape it using requests.